# Foreach overwrites list items even though new instance is created (INSIDE) c#

Tags: c#

```
private List<Adapter> GetAllIPV4Interfaces()
    {
        var adapters = new List<Adapter>();
        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach(var nic in interfaces)
        {

            var ipAddress = nic.GetIPProperties()
                .UnicastAddresses.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && 
                    !IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip.Address));
            if (ipAddress != null)
            {                                  
                adapters.Add(new Adapter{IPAdress = ipAddress.Address.ToString(), Name = nic.Name});
            }
        }
        return adapters;
    }
```

The above code, goes through all available Nics and gets the ones with an IPV4 address that isn't a loopback (127.0.0.1) and
as you can see, I am infact adding a new instance of the Adapter class to my list of Adapters, inside my Loop.
But, it overwrites the entire list with the new Adapter as it normally would have, if i hadn't created the new instance of my object

Can anybody please shed some light on this?
I'm at the point where I'm pulling out hair
this maybe a case of overlooking a simple thing, i've stared myself blind on this.

The adapter class just has 2 string properties.

PS
if i use a list of strings and concatinate the ip and name into one string.. this code works fine.

just in case
my Adapter class

```
class Adapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ip address.
        /// </summary>
        public string IPAdress
        {
            get { return _ipAdress; }
            set { _ipAdress = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the _name.
        /// </summary>
        private static string _name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the _ip adress.
        /// </summary>
        private static string _ipAdress { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid, from you code, it is not possible to find the issue..

Comment: Exactly.. I really don't get, why I'm getting these results. but I really am :S

Comment: How `adapters` are defined?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see where exactly the list of adapters is getting written? I think we need more code, and I think you may be looking in the wrong spot. It's a List<Adapter>, right?

Comment: I bet the problem is how you call `GetAllIPV4Interfaces();`

Comment: how can this be a problem when its the results of the method (even while stepping through) thats the problem?. the code is behaving like im not creating a new instance of Adapter, although I clearly am

Comment: As an aside, here's an example of how to do this without the foreach or the null check... https://gist.github.com/cwharris/2504d6884c7f5a8eed0b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that the fields of your `Adapter` class are declared as `static`. Take the `static` keyword off both properties and it won't show this behaviour:

```
private string _name;
private string _ipAdress;
```

Having them as `static` means that all instances of the `Adapter` class are sharing the same value for storage.

Comment: @AlexInTime: Just noticed that you are using private properties instead of fields. There is no need to do this, so either convert them to fields, or use a public getter and private setter on an automatic property.